# perl script using XML parser to read values in text file and replace it xml file

Tags: perl

Perl script using XML parser to read values in text file and replace it in xml file

how to read xml tag and replace value from text file value. if an entry value is null in install.properties then same has to be updated in property.xml and if entry value is null xml it should get updated with text file value

install.properties text file

```
TYPE = Patch
LOCATION = 
HOST = 127.1.1.1
PORT = 8080
```

property.xml file before values are replaced

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="TYPE">Release</entry>
    <!-- tst  -->
    <entry key="LOCATION">c:/release</entry>
    <entry key="HOST">localhost</entry>    
    <entry key="PORT"></entry>    

</properties>
```

property.xml file after values has been replaced

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="TYPE">Patch</entry>
    <!-- tst  -->
    <entry key="LOCATION"></entry>
    <entry key="HOST">127.1.1.1</entry>    
    <entry key="PORT">8080</entry>    

</properties>
```

Comment: I am trying it on Windows 7 64 bit OS and there is some issue with installing XML-XSH2 through ppm or cpan.
Please suggest any other solution.

Answer (score 6):

A solution using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::XSH2;

open my $INS, '<', 'install.properties' or die $!;

while (<$INS>) {
    chomp;
    my ($var, $val) = split / = /;        # / fix StackOverflow syntax highlighting.
    $XML::XSH2::Map::ins->{$var} = $val;
}

xsh << '__XSH__';
open property.xml ;
for /properties/entry {
    set ./text() xsh:lookup('ins', @key) ;
}
save :b ;
__XSH__
```

The same programme imlemented using only `XML::LibXML`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::LibXML;

open my $INS, '<', 'install.properties' or die $!;

my %ins;
while (<$INS>) {
    chomp;
    my ($var, $val) = split / = /;  # / fix StackOverflow syntax highlighting.
    $ins{$var} = $val;
}

my $xml = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml( location => 'property.xml' );
for my $entry( $xml->findnodes('/properties/entry')) {
    my ($text) = $entry->findnodes('text()');
    $text->setData($ins{ $entry->getAttribute('key') });
}
rename 'property.xml', 'property.xml~';
$xml->toFile('property.xml');
```

Comment: on Windows 7 64 bit having some problem with ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides XML::XSH2 
no luck with CPAN also
can you please suggest some other option

Comment: Use XML::LibXML would be fine,

Comment: what if an entry is not updated? This would remove the value wouldn't it?

Comment: @mirod: Yes. You can test whether `xsh:lookup` returns anything, and you should probably only loop over `/properties/entry[@key]`. The specification was not detailed enough :-)

Comment: yes mirod, if entry is null then same should be updated. your solution works fine, but adds a space before the value in xml file

Comment: @Vivek that's because there was a typo in the code, it was missing a \ before the second s in the split regexp. I have updated the code and it works fine now

Comment: @choroba Thanks for the XML::LibXML sample code, but i am getting this msg **Can't call method "setData" on an undefined value at writexml3.pl line 19, <$INS> line 50**
also if an entry value is null in install.properties then same has to be updated in property.xml else its adding next entry name in xml file

Comment: @Vivek: Do you know any Perl? Check that the value exists before making the change.

Comment: @choroba Sorry, it was my mistake that i missed the some part of the requirement. its working fine if xml file has all values. but if any value is null/empty then its failing with the msg

Answer (score 1):

Again, with XML::Twig:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie qw( open);

use XML::Twig;

my $IN= "install.properties";
my $XML= "properties.xml";

# load the input file into a a hash key => value
open( my $in, '<', $IN);
my %entry= map { chomp; split /\s*=\s*/; } <$in>;


XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { entry => \&entry, },
                keep_spaces => 1,
              )
         ->parsefile_inplace( $XML);

 sub entry
  { my( $t, $entry)= @_;
    if( my $val= $entry{$entry->att( 'key')} )
      { $entry->set_text( $val); }
    $t->flush;
  }
```

Comment: its working fine with all values in install.properties, but if one entry is null then the next entry name is getting updated in xml file

Comment: what do you mean by 'one entry is null'? An entry in the `install.properties` file, or an entry in the XML file?

Comment: if an entry in install.properties like LOCATION = has no value then in xml its adding value as HOST in LOCATION entry. I have updated the my question with one more entry in install.properties and xml file

Comment: Oh, you need to change the part that reads that file then. It should look like `my %entry; while( <$in>) { chomp; my $(k, $v)= split /\s*=\s*/; $entry{$k}= $v if $k; }`. You should be able to do this on your own.